# SVG вычесть набор из другого набора

Tags: svg

Приветствую. Есть вот такой пример SVG:

```html
<svg height="25cm" width="25cm">
 <g transform="translate(945,0) rotate(0) scale(-1, 1)" >
  <g id='mask'><g transform="translate(277.68834228516, 136.08)"><g transform="scale(0.0784423828125) translate(0, 0)"><path transform="translate(0,0) rotate(0) scale(1, -1)" d="M156 1167q41 203 57 267h1061q-16 -63 -57 -267h-381l-248 -1167h-297l248 1167h-383z"></path><path transform="translate(1124,0) rotate(0) scale(1, -1)" d="M41 0l305 1434h879l-58 -269h-569l-61 -291h532q-8 -29 -57 -268h-533l-69 -327h585l-59 -279h-895z"></path><path transform="translate(2293,0) rotate(0) scale(1, -1)" d="M111 715q78 354 327.5 544.5t558.5 190.5q238 0 397.5 -131t155.5 -381h-288q-16 133 -98.5 183t-223.5 50q-199 0 -338 -130t-182 -334q-43 -188 41 -315.5t282 -127.5q279 0 410 258h313q-68 -180 -197.5 -305t-276 -178t-304.5 -53q-303 0 -475 194.5t-102 534.5z"></path><path transform="translate(3843,0) rotate(0) scale(1, -1)" d="M156 1167q41 203 57 267h1061q-16 -63 -57 -267h-381l-248 -1167h-297l248 1167h-383z"></path></g></g></g>
  <g transform="translate(8.0325,8.0325)" fill="#4162AC"><g transform="translate(277.68834228516, 136.08)"><g transform="scale(0.0784423828125) translate(0, 0)"><path transform="translate(0,0) rotate(0) scale(1, -1)" d="M156 1167q41 203 57 267h1061q-16 -63 -57 -267h-381l-248 -1167h-297l248 1167h-383z"></path><path transform="translate(1124,0) rotate(0) scale(1, -1)" d="M41 0l305 1434h879l-58 -269h-569l-61 -291h532q-8 -29 -57 -268h-533l-69 -327h585l-59 -279h-895z"></path><path transform="translate(2293,0) rotate(0) scale(1, -1)" d="M111 715q78 354 327.5 544.5t558.5 190.5q238 0 397.5 -131t155.5 -381h-288q-16 133 -98.5 183t-223.5 50q-199 0 -338 -130t-182 -334q-43 -188 41 -315.5t282 -127.5q279 0 410 258h313q-68 -180 -197.5 -305t-276 -178t-304.5 -53q-303 0 -475 194.5t-102 534.5z"></path><path transform="translate(3843,0) rotate(0) scale(1, -1)" d="M156 1167q41 203 57 267h1061q-16 -63 -57 -267h-381l-248 -1167h-297l248 1167h-383z"></path></g></g></g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Представляет из себя набор текста превращенный побуквенно в path. Сложность появилась когда понадобилось вычесть один слой из другого (subtract). Перепробовал маски и clipPath, но не получилось. Может подскажете правильный путь?

Answer (score 0):

создаете в Inkscape или другом векторном редакторе, любой объект, сохраняете в svg. Открываете Notepad++ ищете теги `<g></g>`. То что между ними удаляете и вставляете свой участок кода, который между `<g></g>`. Сохраняете. Открываете редактор. И правите. Оставляю ссылку на файл(6 дней) на DropMe - [ТЫК](http://dropmefiles.com/kgXPg)!

Comment: И получаем белый лист на выходе. Попробуйте открыть свой свг в браузере.